# Movie about restaurant where girl fall in love with chef, Language-English

Tags: identify-this-movie

I have seen a movie which revolve around restaurant. Let me recollect what I remember.

Lead girl is an amazing cook or chef in her surrounding. People who has tested her cooked food loved it. However she has a dream to work with top chef who has a restro in her city. She always reads her magazine where all the latest food related stuff is published and is one of the main magazine.

Things lead to one and another and she joins her idol chef restro as a cook or jr. chef. She meets the head chef(lead guy) who is working with this restro for 10 years and is master of food(legacy food, as he is been doing it since 10 years). Lead girl adjust to new situation and then tries her creativity in the evenings when everybody lefts but her boss(TOP CHEF) once caught her post working hours and finds she has been trying to cook something else which she taste and give ok ok nod to lead girl but deep down she actually liked her dish. She scold her as this is not the restro policy to try ur stuff post working hours but allows her to do but secretly as she has an evil idea to steal her recipes through CCTV.

They I think they have a fallout few days later and she leaves the job. She opens up her own restro. The opening night is some holiday season first day or something where they make lead girls recipes and food critics was supposed to visit to write a review in newspapers. This is the time she find out her recipes are stolen. She confronts her idol. Then next day she gets a news of don't remember.

But I do remember that the lead chef from the boss's office and the lead girl fall in love. Ups and downs during entire story.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[***A Dash of Love***](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt6286216/) (2017 Hallmark Movie)

> An aspiring chef lands her dream job working for her idol, who then betrays her by stealing her recipes. However, the young culinary enthusiast sets a new goal for herself when she and a charming executive chef work to create a pop-up restaurant.
>
> <sup>[Rotten Tomatoes](https://www.rottentomatoes.com/m/a_dash_of_love/)</sup>

[**Full Plot**](https://www.inquisitr.com/3970666/a-dash-of-love-in-hallmark-tv-movie-chef-discovers-food-love-and-romance/)

> Nikki Turner has been working as a cook in the Flo Two Diner for a while. But when the diner closes down suddenly, Nikki finds herself without a job. Opportunity comes her way when she gets the chance to work for Holly Hanson, a famous culinary book author with her own restaurant.
>
> Holly Hanson hires Nikki as her assistant. But there is a catch: Nikki can’t cook in the restaurant just yet. Seeing that Nikki is passionate and determined to hone in on her craft. Holly allows Nikki to stay at the restaurant after closing time so that she can work on her recipes and tasty dishes.
>
> However, Holly Hanson isn’t just being nice, she has a plan: to steal Nikki’s recipes by using a hidden camera that will record her every cooking move after hours.
>
> Without her knowledge, Nikki designs and creates the most delicious recipes with the intention of using them someday when she steps into the role of chef. But Nikki’s dream is destroyed when Holly fires her, along with executive chef Paul Delucci, after she catches them on camera in the kitchen after work.
>
> Soon Nikki realizes that hiring and firing her was all part of Holly Hanson’s plan to steal her scrumptious recipes to rebuild her own brand by offering new dishes for her restaurant while passing them off as her own creations.
>
> Paul Delucci develops deep romantic feelings for Nikki and wants to help her come up with the perfect plan to fight back. Together they set up a 3-day opening at Nikki’s old stomping ground–the Flop Two Diner–in the hopes that they will drum up enough support to open permanently.